# listing and Scilab code

Tags: listings

I want to insert Scilab code in a listing environment

```
\begin{lstlisting}[]
function y = f(x)
y = 1/sqrt(2*\%pi) * exp(-x^2/2)
endfunction
\end{lstlisting}
```

but it then displays "\%" whereas I would like it to display "%" only ...
Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`lslisting` environment is similar to `verbatim` environment. So just use `%`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}             % Include the listings-package
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[]
function y = f(x)
y = 1/sqrt(2*%pi) * exp(-x^2/2)
endfunction
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found !

just write

```
%
```

it sounds like a comment, but is not interpreted...